# Showing delete link for creator of comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got my app working so that the user can only delete their own comments but now im trying to add a link to the site but i only want the creator of the comment to be able to see the link.

I tried doing

```
<% if current_user %>
```

but when i do that it shows up on all comments and not just the user. I can do

```
<% if current_user.admin %>
```

and that restricts only the admin to be able to see the delete links. I've also tried

```
 <% if @comment.user_id == current_user.id %>
```

that doesent work either. How can i do it so that the comment creator can only see the comments?

heres my view

_comments.html.erb

```
  <div class="container">
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div class="comment">
<div class="gravatar_border">
  <%= gravatar_for comment.user, size: '49' %>
</div>

<div class="user_info_comments">
  <b><%= comment.user.name %></b>
  <%= comment.created_at.strftime("%b. %d  %Y") %>
</div>

<div class="user_comments">
  <%= simple_format comment.content %> 
  <%= pluralize comment.reputation_value_for(:votes).to_i, "vote" %>
  <%= link_to "", vote_comment_path(comment, type: 'up'), method: "post", class: ' icon-thumbs-up' %>
  <%= link_to "", vote_comment_path(comment, type: 'down'), method: "post", class: ' icon-thumbs-down' %>
  <% if @comment.user_id == current_user.id %>
  <%= link_to 'delete', comment, method: :delete, confirm: 'you sure?' %>
  <% end %>
   </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
 <br />
</div>
```

heres my controller

comments_controller.rb

```
  def destroy
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
      if @comment.user_id == current_user.id
        @comment.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "comment deleted!"
      else
        flash[:error] = "not allowed"
      end
   redirect_to :back
 end
```

heres a link to the site http://www.batman-fansite.com

Comment: Assuming you're actually storing a user's `:id` in the `:user_id` column of your `comments` table, your last attempt should be working just fine **for any comment `current_user` actually authored**. That aside you really need to show more of your code for us to help.

Comment: i do have user_id in my comments table....the last piece of code is whats in my comments controller for destroy so that only people that created the comment can delete it...i thought it should work too but when i put it in my views all the delete links dissapear

Comment: Probably because your `current_user` didn't author any of the comments. Again, we can't help you unless you show us your view and controller. We can't really help when we're just guessing what your code might look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if comment.user_id == current_user.id %>
```

and should work)

Comment: But what if current_user is nil? Not logged in?  Append your code: <% if current_user && (comment.user_id == current_user.id) %> or <% if current_user && (comment.user == current_user) %>

Comment: Per Valery's first answer I do this: `if current_user.try(:user_id) == comment.user_id`

Comment: In this case .try(:id) returns nil if current_user is nil. So, if in any way comment's user_id is nil, link will be show up to everybody who is not logged in. :) Short - not always right )

Answer (score 2):

Change `@comment` to `comment` in your view.

```
<% if comment.user_id == current_user.id %>
```

`@comment` is defined in your `destroy` action, but when you setup a block like this in your view

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
```

`@comment` has no value, only `comment` does.

Comment: Providing your code up front next time will save everyone time and get you your answer faster.